# How can I make a scrollable matrix in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to build a simple app that will show a bidimensional, scrollable matrix of square tiles. Imagine a 2D Rubick's Cube, where you can choose to scroll a single row or a single column as if it was a ring.

I've placed a `RelativeLayout` inside the main view, and placed all the tiles of the matrix inside of it, through a custom implementation of the `ImageView` component. I set the exact position of the single tile manipulating its `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` value:

```
RelativeLayout rl = ...;
TileView tile = ...;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(size, size);
rlp.setMargins(left, top, 0, 0);
rl.addView(tile, rlp);
```

I really do not like this approach since I would like to change the top and left parameters of the tile instead of the margins, but that's the best I have been able to do.

I attached a listener to each tile to handle the dragging of the relative row or column, depending on the direction of the dragging event. Everything seems to work quite fine, except for a few problems:

1. When I scroll a row to the right, the last tile on the right margin will progressively shrink as if it was trying to fill the remaining space, and will eventually disappear.
2. When I then scroll back to the left the disappeared tiles will not reappear.

Furthermore, I still have to figure what is the best way to give the user the illusion of an infinite row/column. I think I should replicate all the tiles on both sides of each row/column, probably only when that row/column is being scrolled.

I am asking you for help just to understand what you think is the best way to realize this interface, since I think I am messing up with the code. If you need any more details, just ask me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were doing this, my inclination would be to go at it at a lower level than you are.  I'd use a [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) as the main View and render the tiles with [Canvas.drawBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Paint%29).  It probably sounds like more work, but I think that it's the right way to do what you're trying to do, and that ultimately you'll be happier with the results.

To address your two problems:

1. The version of `drawBitmap()` I linked to lets you specify the subset of the Bitmap to draw, so you can clip the tile rather than shrinking it as it goes off the screen.
2. You'll be responsible for determining what goes where (and drawing it there), so your data structure representing the tile matrix needs to represent off-screen tiles as well.

Comment: I chose to use different views for each to have a better way to handle touch and scroll event on the rows/columns. If I use a single `SurfaceView` instead, how should I handle those events? In that case I would have a single big view and should use the coordinates to find the tile I am touching?

Comment: Yeah, like I said, it's lower level -- so you'll have to do a little math to convert touch coordinates to tile row/column coordinates, and proceed from there.  There's a certain threshold of uniqueness in what you're doing at which point dropping to a lower level makes things easier, even though little things like figuring out which tile is touched become slightly harder.  I'd say what you're doing sounds game-like, and most games do something along the lines the I suggest.

Comment: I think that even animations will be harder to handle. I mean, if I need to start an animation for a single tile to make it disappear (working on the alpha channel), I think that also will be quite difficult to perform at this lower level ...

Comment: It is a bit harder but not that bad.  Reading the documentation to [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) and the [2D graphics Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) was enough to get me up and running.  

I know you want to keep it simple and leverage `Views` and `Layouts`, but I'd be surprised if you got that to work well.  I think the reason you're having trouble is that you're already pushing up against the limits of what they can do for you.